# Windows like look and feel in web application

Tags: asp.net, css

I want my application to look like windows (xp/vista/7)(all the font etc). Can someone suggest where to get the css?

Comment: You are talking about web application, right ??

Comment: Aw... asking for the css takes the fun out of web-development

Comment: check this if you are looking for style your web app as like windows using css..
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/WinFormStyleSheet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [tutorial/source](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2010/04/06/windows-7-start-menu-css3.aspx) of exactly what you want. Here is a [demo](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/windows7menu/) of this live.
Hopefully after reviewing this source you see how easy CSS3 is to use to make styles instead of asking someone to make it for you. 
Also if you want practically a functional desktop, that will take 30+ hours to make with HTML5 and CSS3, not something someone is just going to give you the source to.

Answer (score 0):

This is done completely with CSS, it works just like a Windows desktop, but it is done completely in CSS.

Refer this http://trendydna.blogsome.com/2005/05/09/windows-xp-css-desktop/

Here is the [Demo](http://desktop.trovster.com/)

Comment: gah that was painful. I did not like all the redirects to the actual websites of the icons. i was trying to see what the desktop did not view products. any if your interested in something like this. my user page has a link to my website which is a completely functional desktop.